# Laravel mail error Call to a member function subject() on a non-object

Tags: email, laravel

I have written this code to send mails for user one their order is completed

```
public function complete(Request $request)
{
    $id=$request->input('ResID');
    $del=DB::table('res')->where('ReservationID',$id)->update(array('Status'=>'Completed'));
    $name=$request->input('UserName');
    Mail::send('email',array('user'=>$name,),function($message)
    {
        $message->to(Input::get('UserEmail'),Input::get('UserName')->subject('Youre order has been Completed'));
    }
    );
    return view('/DeleteOrder');
}
```

And it return the error Call to a member function `subject()` on a non-object

Answer (score 1):

You've forgot closing parenthesis - `)`:

```
$message->to(Input::get('UserEmail'), Input::get('UserName'))->subject('Youre order has been Completed');
```

You code will try to call `subject()` method on `Input::get('UserName')`, but not on the `$message` object.